# using sscanf for space delimiter reading from file C++

Tags: c++, file, scanf

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
ifstream ifile;
char fName[30][30];
long int uTime[30][10];
ifile.open("sync.log");
char ch;
string str = "";
if(ifile.fail())
{
    cout<<"Invalid File Name!";
    system("pause");
    exit(1);

}
int i = 0;
while(!ifile.eof())
{
    getline(ifile, str);
    cout<<str<<endl;
    sscanf(str.c_str(),"%ld %[^\n]",&uTime[i],fName[i]);

    i++;
    str = "";

}

ifile.close();
system("pause");    
cout<<"Output:"<<endl;
for(i = 0 ;  i < 2 ; i ++)
{
    cout<<uTime[i]<<"   ";
    cout<<fName[i];
    cout<<endl;
}


getch();
return 0;
```

}

**File :** sync.log 
**Format:**
1399865017 Test1.txt 
1399865017 Test1.txt

so here is my full code and i have sync.log file in root directory where the VC++ saved the projects...

It must be stored like this in array after Reading from File 
 uTime[0] = 1399865017; 
 fName[0] = "Test1.txt";  

 fName[1] = "Test1.txt";

**with this above code i am getting**  
uTime[0] = 0012F6B0 and fName[0] = "Test1.txt"

and i want this 
 uTime[0] = 1399865017; 
 fName[0] = "Test1.txt";

Comment: You're not showing where you write the output file. Considering the problems is with the output, that code miiiiiight be relevant.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. How can it "take hexadecimal values from the file" if the text file contains decimal values. Presumably you're printing them as hex.

Comment: Please show us the code where you output `uTime[i]`.

Comment: @BillXia check out the code i have posted ..

Comment: I don't get it. Are you looking for the `std::hex` IO manipulator? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to use:

```
long int uTime[30];
```

instead of

```
long int uTime[30][10];
```

With that, the line that reads data into `uTime` and the line that write `uTime` to `cout` would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have:

```
long int uTime[30][10];
```

when you do:

```
cout << uTime[i] << …
```

you are printing a pointer to an array of 10 `long`.  That pointer is formatted in hex; that is why you are getting hex output.

You need to fix the `sscanf()` call — you've got a bogus argument of `&uTime[i]` there — and the output too.  Since it is not clear why `uTime` is a 2D array, it isn't easy to tell you how to fix it, but the simplest solution would be to drop the `[10]` from the array definition.

Comment: i am using uTime 2D because i want to store multiple values from file... and please look at above my question i have edited it now it's clear..

Comment: You have written `uTime[0] = 1399865017;` but that assignment isn't sensible — I'm surprised it compiles (it won't compile for me because I tell the compiler to treat warnings as errors).  You need to specify `uTime[0][0] = 1399865017;` to assign to one of the elements of the 2D array.  And in your `sscanf()` and in your `cout <<` 'calls', you need to specify 2 dimensions for your 2D array to make any sense: `sscanf(…, &uTime[i][0], …);` and `cout << uTime[i][0] …`.

Comment: ok thanks fixed i just changed long int uTime[10]; i am stupid why i am using 2d array i don't see that Anyway Thanks again.. :)

Comment: Since you have space for 30 names (each of 30 characters), don't you need 30 `uTime` values too?